# Sqlite Database Took a long time to retrieve data in iOS. It takes 5 Min to show data

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

```
- (NSMutableArray*)getEmployeeDetailsByEmployeeName:(int)postid
{
    NSMutableArray *recordSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [self closeanyOpenConnection];


    NSString *fetchQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from SubCategory_Content where SubcategoryID==%d",postid];

    const char *selectQuery = [fetchQuery UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlstatement = nil;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(databaseReference, selectQuery, -1, &sqlstatement , NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {

        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

        while (sqlite3_step(sqlstatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            char* PostIDchar = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(sqlstatement, 1);
            NSString *PostID = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:PostIDchar];
            [dict setValue:PostID forKey:@"PostID"];

            char* ShortContentChar = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(sqlstatement, 2);
            NSString *ShortContentStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:ShortContentChar];
            [dict setValue:ShortContentStr forKey:@"ShortContent"];

            char* imageDataFromDatabase = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(sqlstatement, 4);
            NSString *ShortContentImage = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:imageDataFromDatabase];
            [dict setValue:ShortContentImage forKey:@"ShortContentImage"];

            char* titleChar = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(sqlstatement, 5);
            NSString *titlestr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:titleChar];
            [dict setValue:titlestr forKey:@"Title"];

            [recordSet addObject:dict];

            imageDataFromDatabase = nil;

            dict = nil;

            dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        }

        dict = nil;
    }

    return  recordSet;
}
```

Comment: And? IS there a question here or what is this all about?

Comment: add some description with your code about your problem, so that someone can understand and guide you.

Comment: I have applied this code to fetch data from database..yes data is fetching correctly ... But when i click button to fetch this data ..it took almost 5 min to fetch this data .. This is my problem

Comment: Is anyone there who can help me

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more details, I would suggest creating an index on the SubcategoryID column if you have not already done that, so using a sqlite3_exec call to execute "CREATE INDEX idx_SubcategoryID ON SubCategory_Content (SubcategoryID ASC)".

You should see a dramatic improvement in performance, if that was in fact the query was your problem.

If you were only ever expecting one result from your query then definitely add "LIMIT 1" to the end of your statement, but having added an index you would have mitigated this shortfall.

You are also asking it to do a lot of work storing and retrieving image data as text.  I would suggest storing them as a BLOB value instead if you can make that kind of change in your application.

To start though I would setup some break points around the SELECT statement to see if that is in fact your slowdown, it most likely is.

Thanks